# вывод процента вероятности правильного обнаружения объекта с помощью Emgu CV (C#)

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

С помощью OpenCV создал каскад Хаара для отдельного объекта. После, на C# с помощью Emgu CV написал приложение которое в реальном времени (с использованием веб камеры) обнаруживает этот объект. Подскажите как сделать чтобы вместе с выделением объекта он выводил процент вероятности правильного обнаружения объекта?

Comment: Проблема в том, чтобы нарисовать текст или узнать значение этой вероятности?

Comment: узнать вероятность